# Why default import of module is include the default export again in importing

Tags: javascript, node-modules, javascript-import

I am trying to import the [react-ga4 npm package.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga4)

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga4'
```

The package is imported with default as follows when I console logging

[image: default import]

I am confused here as it is the behaviour of importing as

```
import * as ReactGA from 'react-ga4'
```

state in [Mozilla Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#default_import)

even in the usage guide of [react-ga4 npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga4), the initialize method is directly accessed as

`import ReactGA from "react-ga4";`
`ReactGA.initialize("your GA measurement id");`

not like `ReactGA.default.initialize("")`. So am I something missing or misunderstood here.

It is not re-producible in codesandbox : [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-water-ig31c8?file=/src/index.js) 
but the error persists at new npm package

Comment: That's likely a compatibility hack. People write some extremely bizarre non-standard Imports and transpilers have supported these forms over the years. Do not reference the nested default property.

Comment: I am also curious why this has happened to only me. I have read articles and its github issues, this situation is not addressed so it seems like it is only happening to me.

Comment: I couldn't say, but I've encountered this issue both in questions on SO and in my own experience interoperating between various module loaders and transpilers. For example, working with SystemJS + TypeScript + Babel + template loaders in Aurelia. These are all great tools but the standards were constantly changing underneath of the implementers and everything was in flux.

Comment: @echo did you find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

When you import module without curly brackets like this`

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga4'
```

the package name whatever it is (ReactGA or something else), it references automatically to default exported values. So here your 'ReactGA' is the same default exported object.
When you import with asterisk

```
import * as ReactGA from 'react-ga4'
```

yor 'ReactGA' contains all exported values

You can import default exported and named exported values in one line

```
import ReactGA, { ReactGAImplementation } from 'react-ga4'
```

here your ReactGA is default.

for mor info you can read this artice` https://betterprogramming.pub/built-in-module-imports-and-exports-javascript-es6-feature-series-part-7-5f0864049e1f

Comment: yes I noticed that dude, but when I import without curly bracket, it is supped to only import the default exported values but here it consists all exported values. and this error is not reproducible in codesandbox (link added to posts) but the error is persists in new different repo.